# How to convert cancellable subscription to Cat's IO

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

In one of my projects, I have to use a callback-based asynchronous API. I wanted to introduce `cats IO`, yet I have some troubles with it:

```
IO.cancelable { cb =>
  val subscription = createSubscription(
     ...,
     (msg: Message) => cb { Right("SomeResult") }
  )
  IO {subscription.unsubscribe()}
}
```

It looks quite nice, however I also need to `unsubscribe` after receiving a message. Unfortunately `IO {subscription.unsubscribe()}` is evaluated only in the case of cancellation. 
I can make a quick workaround, but it seems very counter-intuitive :

```
IO.cancelable { cb =>
  lazy val subscription = createSubscription(
     ...,
     (msg: Message) => cb {
       subscription.unsubscribe() //I can't be really sure if subscription is already initialized
       Right("SomeResult")
     }
  )
  subscribe //I have to ensure evalutaion of lazy val
  IO {subscription.unsubscribe()}
}
```

I have checked cats-effects doc, sadly I didn't find anything that could help me with this problem. I can think of some bullet-proof solutions for this issue, yet it seems so typical that I can't believe that it wasn't already solved.

Is there any simple way to achieve this resource release behavior using `cats`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Resource`s:

```
import cats.effect.{ IO, Resource }

val subscriptionResource: Resource[IO, Subscription] =
  Resource.make {
    IO { createSubscription(...) }
  } { subscription =>
    IO { subscription.unsubscribe() }
  }
```

used as:

```
subscriptionResource.use { subscription =>
  // your IO routine
}
```

This is a (composable) way of making sure that your resource will be released no matter if there is an error or success. (Though, I don't remember what happens in case of cancellation as it was a trick subject - probably in such case `release` block wouldn't be called).

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve my issue. I have checked docs regarding `Resource` earlier. It indeed can be cancellable and asynchronous, however I couldn't find a method that provides async completion callback (like `IO.cancelable { cb =>`).

Comment: Do you want to cancel IO or decide yourself when to complete it?

Comment: Perhaps you want `Async` (https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/async.html) for completing IO combined with `Resource` for handling resource closing?